# Getting all children and subchildren from parent JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a table TABLE that can have parents of the same type.
In Java the child can reach the parent but the parent doesn't have a list of children.

In MySQL I was able to create the following query that gives me the children and subchildren of the parent, but I'm unable to translate this into JPA Java.

How can I translate this query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE AS T1 
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE.parentId = 966) AS T2 
  ON T2.id = T1.parentId OR T1.parentId = 966 
GROUP BY T1.id
```

Into java language, using Criteria builder and Criteria Query, I already tried something like this:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<TABLE> cq = cb.createQuery(TABLE.class);
    Root<TABLE> tABLE= cq.from(TABLE.class);

    Predicate result = cb.conjunction();

    Join<TABLE, TABLE> TABLEJoin = tABLE.join("parent", JoinType.INNER);
    result = cb.and(result, cb.equal(genericLocationJoin.get("parent"), location));
em.createQuery(cq.select(tAble).where(result)).getResultList();
```

But this only gives me the direct children, it doesn't give me the subchildren.

Thank you for your help.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
public final class TABLE {

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 20)
    private String externalId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId", nullable = true)
    private TABLE parent;
}
```

Comment: Post your entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this in the domain model by making the relationship bi-directional and writing a recursive method to walk the tree. One advantage of this is that it will handle children to any level.

This would look something like the below and then for any instance you can do:

```
SomeEntity e = //;
e.getChildren(); //only direct children
e.getAllChildren(); //all children
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_entity")
public final class SomeEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 20)
    private String externalId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId", nullable = true)
    private SomeEntity parent;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<SomeEntity> children; //or Set<>
    
    //returns direct children
    public List<SomeEntity> getChildren(){
        return children;
    } 
    
    //returns all children to any level
    public List<SomeEntity> getAllChildren(){
        getAllChildren(this);
    }
    
    //recursive function to walk the tree
    private List<SomeEntity> getAllChildren(SomeEntity parent){
        List<SomeEntity> allChidren = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for(SomeEntity child : parent.getChildren()){
            allChildren.add(child);
            allChildren.addAll(getAllChildren(child);
        }
        
        return allChildren;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much i think that's a good enough solution for this case, the problem was I was trying to do all in one query.

Comment: Okay, I made a slight edit. Haven't tested  the recursive part but is hopefully okay after edit.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it will have a great impact on the database since the object will always request for the child and in the must cases that is not what is suppose to do. The default is to have a parent and not request the child but in some situations it will be needed that relation. That 's why is was trying to implement a query that can be used when needed and not all the time that you ask for the entity.

Comment: The child collection is lazily  loaded so I am not sure I understand.

Comment: I saw a way of doing is adding a path for each entity, for instance, root parent with id 1 will be / and it's child would have /1/ a so on, with this you can make a query that gets all childs for each parent.

Comment: Can anyone help on the below issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76154920/getting-handler-dispatch-failed-nested-exception-is-java-lang-stackoverflowerro