# Get whole parent hierarchy

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

If I have a class like this:

```
@Entity
public class Node {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_NODE_ID")
    private Node parent;
}
```

What would be the easiest/most elegant way of getting all parent hierarchy of a node?

something like: `List<Node> getTheWholeParentHierarchy(Node node);`

Comment: In Java  use a recursive method to walk the tree. See example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459083/getting-all-children-and-subchildren-from-parent-jpa/54464128#54464128. Some databases may provide support for hierarchical queries e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Comment: thank you Alan, was just wondering if one can do it in an elegant lambda way. found also some examples for children that however did not translate well to parents:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
@Entity
public class Node {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "node_id")
   private long nodeId;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
   @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
   @JsonIgnore
   private Node parent;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
   @JsonIgnore
   private Set<Node> subordinates = new HashSet<>();
}
```

when you `nodeRepository.findById()` you can select the node with their parent, and their parent...

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, I believe you should model the other way around :

```
@Entity
public class Node {

   @OneToMany
   private List<Node> children = new ArrayList();
}
```

In this way, you will not need additional preprocessing and you will be able to call parent.getChildren()

Comment: Not what I was looking for.  I want the hierarchy of parents in a concise and effective way...