# Find the Values of multiple layer childs (using loop???)

Tags: spring, jpa

I was not sure about how to search for this so was really unsuccessful. I will just start from data classes that i have,

Here is the TrainingPlan Entity (example)

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRAINING_PLAN")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"trainings"})
public class TrainingPlan {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "CURRENT_PHASE")
private int currentPhase;

@Column(name = "PREVIOUS_TRAINING_PLAN_ID")
private Long previousTrainingPlanId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "trainingPlan", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Training> trainings = new ArrayList<Training>();
```

Here is the Training Entity (example)

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRAINING")
public class Training {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "TRAINING_PLAN_ID")
private TrainingPlan trainingPlan;
```

I hope i will be able to explain this clearly, so what i am trying to achieve here is to get Trainings from all previous (TrainingPlan) phases.

How it works - when next (New TrainingPlan) plan phase is created it references the old Plan with the previousPlanId so it recognises its parent (its like layers).

So, for example, if TrainingPlan has phase 2, i can easily get Trainings from phase 1 in a similar way to this:

```
    public List<Training> trainingsFromPreviousPhase(TrainingPlan plan, List<TrainingPlan> planList) {
    List<Training> previousPhaseTrainings = new ArrayList<Training>();

    if (plan.getPreviousTrainingPlanId() != null) {
        TrainingPlan previousPlanPhase = planList.parallelStream()
                .filter(e -> e.getId() == plan.getPreviousTrainingPlanId()).findAny().get();
        previousPhaseTrainings = previousPlanPhase.getTrainings();

}
    return previousPhaseTrainings;
}
```

Now the problem is if a plan is at Phase 5, i need to get the trainings from all 4 previous phases, and this is where i get stuck, cant think of a method to automatically loop that. I hope i explained this not too hard to understand. Any advices or questions are welcome.

What i need here is something similar to:

```
List<List<Training>> getTrainingsFromAllPreviousPhases()
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you are looking for a recursive function i.e. a method that will call itself and handle any number of nested levels. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459083/getting-all-children-and-subchildren-from-parent-jpa/54464128#54464128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through all plan phases like this:

```
TrainingPlan currentPlan = plan;
List<Training> allTrainings = new ArrayList<>();
while (cirrentPlan.getPreviousTrainingPlanId() != null) {
    TrainingPlan previousPlanPhase = planList.parallelStream()
        .filter(e -> e.getId() == currentPlan.getPreviousTrainingPlanId()).findAny().get();
    allTrainings.addAll(previousPlanPhase.getTrainings());
    currentPlan = previousPlanPhase;
}
```

However, to avoid repeatedly going through the list of plans to find the one by id, I'd propose to keep them in a map:

```
Map<Long, TrainingPlan> planMap = planList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(TrainingPlan::getId, Function.identity());
```

Then the code could be simplified (both visually, and in terms of O(n) complexity):

```
TrainingPlan currentPlan = plan;
List<Training> allTrainings = new ArrayList<>();
while (currentPlan.getPreviousTrainingPlanId() != null) {
    TrainingPlan previousPlanPhase = planMap.get(currentPlan.getPreviousTrainingPlanId());
    allTrainings.addAll(previousPlanPhase.getTrainings());
    currentPlan = previousPlanPhase;
}
```

Comment: Guys you are perfect, that is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you!!! :)