# Getting Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lombok

I have self reference table nh_node which refer itself.

I try to follow [Getting all children and subchildren from parent JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459083/getting-all-children-and-subchildren-from-parent-jpa#comment95793254_54464128) Solution.

Code:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@lombok.Data
@lombok.EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@javax.persistence.Table(name ="nh_node")
public class NodeEntity extends BaseEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    
    private static final String NODE_GENERATOR = "node_generator";

    @javax.persistence.Id
    @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue(strategy =    javax.persistence.GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = NODE_GENERATOR)
    @javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name =NODE_GENERATOR, sequenceName = "node_id_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @javax.persistence.Column(name ="node_id")
    private java.lang.Long nodeId;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name ="node_name",length =32)
    private java.lang.String nodeName;

    @javax.persistence.OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name ="node_id")
    private java.util.List<com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeUserMappingEntity> nodeUsers;

    @javax.persistence.ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name ="node_category_id")
    private com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeCategoryEntity nodeCategory;

    @javax.persistence.OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentNode", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private java.util.List<com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeEntity> childNodes;

    @javax.persistence.ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name ="parent_node_id")
    private com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeEntity parentNode;

    @javax.persistence.OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name ="node_id")
    private java.util.List<com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeNotificationDetailEntity> nodeNotificationDetails;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name ="tenant_id",nullable = true,length =10)
    private java.lang.Long tenantId;


    public java.lang.Long getNodeId() {
        return nodeId;
     }

    public java.lang.Long setNodeId(java.lang.Long  nodeId) {
        return this.nodeId = nodeId;
     }

    public java.lang.String getNodeName() {
        return nodeName;
     }

    public java.lang.String setNodeName(java.lang.String  nodeName) {
        return this.nodeName = nodeName;
     }

    public java.util.List<com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeUserMappingEntity> getNodeUsers() {
        return nodeUsers;
     }

    public java.util.List<com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeUserMappingEntity> setNodeUsers(java.util.List<com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeUserMappingEntity>  nodeUsers) {
        return this.nodeUsers = nodeUsers;
     }

    public com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeCategoryEntity getNodeCategory() {
        return nodeCategory;
     }

    public com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeCategoryEntity setNodeCategory(com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeCategoryEntity  nodeCategory) {
        return this.nodeCategory = nodeCategory;
     }

    public java.util.List<com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeEntity> getChildNodes() {
        return childNodes;
     }

    public java.util.List<com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeEntity> setChildNodes(java.util.List<com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeEntity>  childNodes) {
        return this.childNodes = childNodes;
     }

    public com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeEntity getParentNode() {
        return parentNode;
     }

    public com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeEntity setParentNode(com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeEntity  parentNode) {
        return this.parentNode = parentNode;
     }

    public java.util.List<com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeNotificationDetailEntity> getNodeNotificationDetails() {
        return nodeNotificationDetails;
     }

    public java.util.List<com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeNotificationDetailEntity> setNodeNotificationDetails(java.util.List<com.mt.retail.nodehierarchyservice.entity.NodeNotificationDetailEntity>  nodeNotificationDetails) {
        return this.nodeNotificationDetails = nodeNotificationDetails;
     }

    public java.lang.Long getTenantId() {
        return tenantId;
     }

    public java.lang.Long setTenantId(java.lang.Long  tenantId) {
        return this.tenantId = tenantId;
     }
    
    //returns all children to any level
    public List<NodeEntity> getAllChildren(){
        return getAllChildren(this);
    }

    //recursive function to walk the tree
    private List<NodeEntity> getAllChildren(NodeEntity parent){
        List<NodeEntity> allChildren = new ArrayList<>();

        for(NodeEntity child : childNodes){
            allChildren.add(child);
            allChildren.addAll(getAllChildren(child));
        }
```

In Service:

```
@Override
public NodeDTO getNodeByNodeId(Long nodeId) {
    Optional<NodeEntity> nodeEntity = nodehierarchyRepository.findById(nodeId);
    System.out.println(nodeEntity.get().getAllChildren());
    return null;
}
```

When I try to retrieve the node children I am getting "Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError" exception.

Can I know where I am making a mistake in my code.

Comment: You have an infinite loop. Looking at the original answer there is an obvious  issue and it should be:   for(NodeEntity child : parent.getChildNodes()){...} i.e. iterate the children of the passed entity. Currently it iterates continuously the children of the root entity.